# Boostrap 5 nav bar not closing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Nav bar not closing in responsive mode

All ready added libraies
''''

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <select class="users" id="users">
                <option><a class="nav-link active" href="#">User</a></option>
                <option><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Employee</a></option>
                <option><a class="nav-link active" href="#">Admin</a></option>
                </select>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
      </nav>
```

```

Comment: A a tag is a link, you can't put it inside a select. Check the bootstrap documentation about correct html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <select class="users" id="users">
        <option><a class="nav-link active" href="#">User</a></option>
        <option><a class="nav-link" href="#">Employee</a></option>
        <option><a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin</a></option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have removed the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">` part and now you can see the dropdown menu while changing the resolution.